# How to animate a 3D object along a path, so that two animations are synchronous?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, 3d

I want to create an animation showing the movement of an arrow on a set trajectory.
I created a path in SVG and JS technology and a 3D vector in CSS technology. I created a path animation (using dashed line animation). Unfortunately, I have a problem with creating an arrow animation.

My code:

```js
let r = 15;
let ry = [];// the array of points used to draw a conical helix

function getPoints() {
  var a = 0.8;// angle for the tilt

  for (var t = 0.1; t < 2 * Math.PI; t += 0.008) {
    let x = r * t * Math.cos(6 * t + a);
    let y =
        (r + r / 2 * Math.cos(a)) * t -
        r / 2 * Math.sin(a) * t * Math.sin(6 * t + a) -
        150;

    ry.push({ x, y });
  }
}

getPoints();


//using the points to build the d attribute for the path
let d = `M${ry[0].x},${ry[0].y}L`;

for (let i = 0; i < ry.length; i++) {
  d += `${ry[i].x},${ry[i].y} `;
}

ch.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);


$('#RF1').click(function(){

  $('#ch').removeClass('my_impuls');
  $('#redVec').removeClass('anima');

  $('#ch').addClass('my_impuls');
  $('#redVec').addClass('anima');
});
```

```css
.my {
  border:1px solid; 
  -webkit-transform: translate(180px, 200px);
  -moz-transform: translate(180px, 200px);
  -o-transform: translate(180px, 200px);
  transform: translate(180px, 200px);
  stroke-dasharray: 1300;
}


.my_impuls{
  animation: dash1 5s linear forwards  reverse;
  -webkit-animation: dash1 5s linear forwards  reverse;
}

.my_no_impuls{
  animation: dash2 5s linear forwards  ;
  -webkit-animation: dash2 5s linear forwards  ;
}

@keyframes dash1 {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1250;
  }
}

@keyframes dash2 {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -1300;
  }
}

.container3{
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
}

.perspective {
  perspective: 12000px;
  -webkit-perspective: 12000px;
}

.vec-wrap {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  transform: translateZ(-300px) translateX(92px) translateY(-560px);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) translateY(-557px) translateX(90px);
}

.vec {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  transform-origin: 20px 130px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 20px 130px;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg) ;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg);  

}

.vec .triangle {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.triangle .side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid red;

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 1;
}

.side:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotateX(30deg) translateZ(8px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg) translateZ(8px);
}

.side:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(30deg) translateZ(8px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateX(30deg) translateZ(8px);
}

.side:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(30deg) translateZ(8px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(30deg) translateZ(8px);
}

.side:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(30deg) translateZ(8px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(30deg) translateZ(8px);
}

.vec .arrow {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.arrow .side2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 1;
}

.side2:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: translateZ(5px);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(5px);
}

.side2:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(5px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(5px);
}

.side2:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(5px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(5px);
}

.side2:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(5px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(5px);
}

.arrow .floor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 125px;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 1;
}

.arrow .ceeling {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 8px;
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 1;
}

.anima{
  transform-origin: 20px 130px;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-name: anim;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-name: anim;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: normal;
  -o-animation-duration: 5s;
  -o-animation-name: anim;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-animation-direction: normal;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg); 
  }
  to {
    transform:       
      rotateX(-20deg)
      rotateZ(-10deg) rotateY(360deg) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
      rotateZ(-20deg) rotateY(360deg) scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9) 
      rotateZ(-30deg) rotateY(360deg) scale3d(1, 1, 1)
      rotateZ(-40deg) rotateY(360deg) scale3d(1,1, 1) 
      rotateZ(-50deg) rotateY(360deg) scale3d(1,1,1) 
      rotateZ(-55deg) rotateY(360deg) scale3d(1,1,1)
      rotateZ(-60deg) rotateY(360deg) scale3d(1,1,1) ;  
  } 
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="RF1"> Animate </button> <br>

<div class="container3">

  <svg width="350" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <path class="my" id="ch" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />

    <div class="vec-wrap">

      <div class="vec" id="redVec">
        <div class="triangle">
          <div class="side">
          </div>

          <div class="side">
          </div>

          <div class="side">
          </div>

          <div class="side">
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="arrow">
          <div class="side2">
          </div>

          <div class="side2">
          </div>

          <div class="side2">
          </div>

          <div class="side2">
          </div> 

          <div class="floor">
          </div> 

          <div class="ceeling">
          </div> 


        </div>
      </div>

    </div> 


    
  </svg>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/kolekole/pen/BXBOXd

Do you know how to write an arrow animation so that it moves along a path and synchronized with the path motion?

Comment: Your html is not valid. You open the svg tag but you never close it. The way the path is drawn you can draw the arrow using svg where the tip of the arrow is a point on the path.

Comment: Tag svg is closed. I cannot code the tip of the arrows a point on the path, I can see what I should do